# Rearranging Boolean equations

Tags: boolean-logic

If I have an equation `x=y&z` (boolean AND) is there a way of rearranging this function so as `y=x?z`.  In a similar fashion to normal algebra that `x=y+z` can be rearranged as `y=x-z`.

Similarly, can `x=y|z` (boolean OR) be rearranged to something `y=x?z`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's unrelated to programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about boolean algebra and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to prove that such inversion operators cannot exist.

**For the AND case:**

`false = true  & false` ⇒ `true  = false ? false`
`false = false & false` ⇒ `false = false ? false`

But `false ? false` cannot be `true` and `false` at the same time, so there cannot be an operator `?` with the desired property. ∎

**For the OR case:**

`true = true  | true` ⇒ `true  = true ? true`
`true = false | true` ⇒ `false = true ? true`

But `true ? true` cannot be `true` and `false` at the same time, so there cannot be an operator `?` with the desired property. ∎